# opencv object detection with my own features

Tags: opencv, object, detection, haar-classifier

I want to use openCV objet detection model with my own features "fourrier descriptors".
I know how to do this using the haar features ( the Viola & Jones method ), now i want to use the same processus using my own customised features.
Do you have any idea plz?
Thanks for your help, Amine.

Comment: Just use the match function on your descriptors

Comment: I want to train an adaboost classifier with my descriptors